# Should I build a Language Server for a custom language - vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VSCode extension for a custom language, and wondering if a Language Server is required to format my code.
What I want to do is:

- Remove trailing spaces for all the lines in the file.
- Auto-indent the lines inside the logic structures (for, while, if/else, etc)

So... there's this example code of a Formatter

```
export class CustomFormatter implements vscode.DocumentFormattingEditProvider {
    provideDocumentFormattingEdits(document: vscode.TextDocument): vscode.TextEdit[] {
        const firstLine = document.lineAt(0);
        console.log(firstLine);
        return [vscode.TextEdit.insert(firstLine.range.start, '123456\n')];
    }
}
```

But how do I make it work in an easy way like the `language-configuration.json` does the job while I'm typing code:

[image: auto-indent]

```
"indentationRules": {
    "increaseIndentPattern": "^\\s*(try|catch|for|while|if|else)",
    "decreaseIndentPattern": "^\\s*(}|catch|end|else)"
  }
```

This is not working when I'm pasting code from other files, so I'm in the need of some sort of FormatProvider like the above.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need the language server. In an extension use vscode.workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument to run code that examines a newly opened text document for whitespace.  And use vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument to check text that has been inserted into the document.

An LSP is actually more complicated than an extension. It runs in a separate process and there is a lot you need to know to get the vscode and LSP processes to work together.

Big advantage of the LSP is that all the work it does runs in the separate process and does not slow down the vscode process.